# NtRaiseHardError: members of ULONG array

Tags: c, winapi, ntdll

I'm learning C and recently found out that `NtRaiseHardError` accepts an array of `ULONG` parameters. The first member is a `UNICODE_STRING` string containing a message shown on the screen, but what do I set next?

I couldn't find anything about this in Google so I'm asking here. Is it another string, or a DWORD parameters maybe?

Comment: If you're in the process of learning C, you shouldn't fiddle around with undocumented functions. Maybe you should tell us what you're _actually_ trying to achieve. This might be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: See [Interpreting a Bug Check Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/interpreting-a-bug-check-code).